# Haydn Hob. XIV: Have they been meant for piano or for harpischord?

Tags: piano, classical-music

I am currently exploring Haydn's opus and have come across Hob. XIV. I really would like to know whether these works originally have been meant for the piano or for the harpischord.

I have researched the respective Wikipedia articles (in English and German), but to no avail. The fact that most articles about these works contain the word "piano" in their title unfortunately does not answer the question, because this is a usual mistake even in articles which clearly deal with works for harpischord. I did not see other hints than such indirect and dubious ones.

Looking into the recordings available did not answer the question either. There are recordings from well-known artists with piano as well as with harpischord.

Could somebody provide a starting point / link for further research or directly answer the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly likely for harpsichord.  According to Google, Haydn didn't get hold of a fortepiano until the 1780s, and the works you are referring to were more from the 1760s.

> The scant evidence suggests that the Esterhazy family [Haydn's long-time employer] had no fortepiano before 1781. Only in 1788 Haydn becomes the owner of a fortepiano. This was probably a square piano produced by the Viennese piano builder Johann Schantz. In a letter of the 20th and 27th of June 1790 to Frau von Genzinger, Haydn writes: “Euer Gnaden Solten Ihren zwar sehr guten Flügl (harpsichord) der freylein Peperl überlassen, und fur sich ein neues Fortepiano einschaffen”. [Roughly: Give your harpsichord away and get a new piano.] ([SOURCE](https://www.keesrosenhart.com/en/haydn-harpsichord-or-fortepiano))

Comment: https://www.keesrosenhart.com/en/haydn-harpsichord-or-fortepiano/#:~:text=The%20scant%20evidence%20suggests%20that,Viennese%20piano%20builder%20Johann%20Schantz.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. This is very well thought out and written. I am very grateful that you enabled me to read this. And of course, answer accepted and upvoted.